# What is the best way to determine the physical memory in Server 08? I believe my system props is wrong

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory, system-properties

Basically, is there a concrete way of determining the amount of physical memory installed on a server other than System Properties in Windows Server 2008? I believe that attribute is either bugged or I've been blessed with human error.

*Edit:* This is a rented rig so I can't pop open the box and look for myself.

*Edit2:* I currently have a 32-bit OS so I can't tell by performance metrics

**EDIT** :

I used CPUZ as suggested below which is showing the appropriate amount while the System Properties and the Crucial tool showed 32gb. What could have caused the error there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you install a freeware application on the server ? 
[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php)

> Memory
>   Frequency and timings.
>   Module(s) specification using SPD (Serial Presence Detect) : vendor, serial number, timings table.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open PowerShell.

Paste: get-wmiobject win32_computersystem

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the System Properties or the Performance tab on Task Manager, where it says Physical Memory (MB) under Total.

How much RAM does it show?

EDIT: Try [CPUID](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php), that will also tell you the specs on the machine, including RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you want to double-check what Windows is telling you?

the memory checker on the crucial website?

something like sisoft sandra?

- both of those will look at physical memory installed, which is what you want, I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

Check the BIOS would be my best answer - but I was thinking it would err in the other direction if you are running certain editions of Server 2008 you are limited to 4GB of memory:

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2008

Version / Limit in 32-bit Windows / Limit in 64-bit Windows
Windows Server 2008 Datacenter (full installation) / 64 GB / 2 TB
Windows Server 2008 Datacenter (Server Core installation) / 64 GB / 2 TB
Windows Server 2008 Enterprise / 64 GB / 2 TB
Windows Server 2008 HPC Edition / Not applicable / 128 GB
Windows Server 2008 Standard / 4 GB / 32 GB
Windows Server 2008 for Itanium-Based Systems / Not applicable / 2 TB
Windows Web Server 2008 / 4 GB / 32 GB

If sounds like it is reporting more than you are expecting. I've never heard of that except in the case of human error, as you said! :)

Comment: It apparently was showing the wrong amount. Any idea what could have caused this?

Comment: The OS was showing the wrong amount? Or the BIOS? And, by saying "was" - is it fixed now (after a reboot?)

Comment: I've rebooted a number of times and its still showing the wrong amount.

Comment: The OS - I'm not able to see the BIOS due to it being a dedicated server elsewhere (can only remote in)